# Navbar responsiveness problem - overflow problem?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, navbar

Hi Guys I am a newbie I am trying to create a burger button but for some reason , when I am inspecting the responsiveness it's making my html wide. instead of hiding the navigation links. I will post a picture so it makes sense.

[navbar is not hidden,still able to see it if you scroll left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyGbm.png)

media queries

```
 @media (max-width:1200px) {
    html {
        font-size:49%;
    }

    .navbar {
        padding:1.5rem 2rem;
    }
}

@media (max-width:920px) {
    #menu-btn {
        display: inline-block;
    }
 

    .navbar .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        top:101%;
        right:-100%;
        background-color: hsla(209, 54%, 52%, .7);
        width: 30rem;
        height:calc(100vh - 9.5rem);
        transition: .4s ease-in;

    }

    .navbar .nav-links.active {
        right:0;
    }
    .navbar .nav-links ul {
        display: block;
        margin:2rem 1.5;
        padding:.5rem;
        font-size:1.2rem;
    }
    .navbar .nav-links ul li {
        padding: 2rem 0;
    }


}

@media (max-width:350px) {

    
    .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .navbar .icons {
        margin: 2em 0;
        font-size:1.2rem;
    }
}
```

main css

```
:root {
    --main-color:hsl(209, 54%, 52%);
    --light-color:#69B4DE;
    --white-text-color:#fff;
}

html {
    font-size:62.5%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scroll-padding-top: 9rem;
    height:200vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    
}

* {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif; ;
    
  
}
body {
    background-color:#dfe3ee;
    
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* header section styling starts */

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;
    background: #4287C7;
    margin:1% 3%;
    align-items: center;
    padding:2%;
    /* border-radius: 10px; */
    box-shadow: 0 .3rem .5rem rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 1000;
    /* overflow-y: hidden; */

}

.navbar .logo img {
    height:10em;
}

.navbar .nav-links ul {
    display: flex;
}

.navbar .nav-links ul li {
    margin:0 2em;
}

.navbar .nav-links ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size:1.5em;
}

.navbar .nav-links ul li a:hover,
.navbar .nav-links ul .active,
.navbar .icons i:hover
{ 
    color:#69B4DE;
   
}

.navbar .icons i{
    color:#fff;
    margin:0 .5em;
    font-size:2em;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#menu-btn {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you set the navbar go to right that means the body width gonna take the space of this navbar because the space in right of the body is opened you can scroll right. But it is closed from the left you can not scroll left. if you take your navbar to left `left: -100%;` this gonna work and the navbar is hidden to left. But if you take the navbar to right `right: -100%;` this gonna not work because the space is opened from right you can scroll to view the navbar. The solution for this problem is to set a `width` and `height` to the body tag and finally add `overflow: hidden;` to hide any element out of the body width.

Solution :

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CSS` trick, because I'm not able to see your html code if you want to post your html code navbar that gonna be helpful.
But Use this `CSS` trick, just set `opacity: 0` of the navlinks to 0 and click to open set it to 1 wish is navLinks.active `opacity: 1`

```css
.navbar .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        top:101%;
        right:-100%;
        background-color: hsla(209, 54%, 52%, .7);
        width: 30rem;
        height:calc(100vh - 9.5rem);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: .4s ease-in;
    }

    .navbar .nav-links.active {
        right:0;
        opacity:1;
 }
```

Comment: https://www.lensfieldroadcycles.co.uk/ - this is the publish website , as you can see, if you visit it in mobile view, it's still allowing me to swipe left? I have tried all the things I know but still not doing it ... thank you in advance for any answers

Comment: I think I understand the method just in your `body` add this style `width:100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;` This is gonna work I try it to your website and it work!